# how to update a text in a file line by line

Tags: python-3.x, file, search, replace

I have a text file foo.txt that looks like:

```
first 01
start
some thing 01  
and more 101  
i dont care  
end  
i dont care  
final 01
```

I want to replace all **01** with **10** between the lines ***start*** and ***end*** in the same foo.txt like so:

```
first 01
start
some thing 10
and more 110
i dont care
end
i dont care
final 01
```

The code I have so far looks like:

```
import re
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close
def replace(foo.txt):
    searchStart = re.compile("^start")
    searchEnd = re.compile("^end")
    pattern = "01"
    subst = "10"
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    search = 0
    with open(abs_path,'w') as new_file:
        with open(file_path) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                if searchEnd.search(line):
                    search = 0
                elif searchStart.search(line):
                    search = 1
                if search == 1:
                    new_file.write(re.sub(pattern,subst,line))
                else:
                    new_file.write(line)
    close(fh)
    remove(foo.txt)
    move(abs_path, foo.txt)
```

It does what i want but I wanted to know if there is any other efficient way for writing the code. I am from an embedded background and so i was using *flag* such as *search* in my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of your use case for wanting to read and write the file line by line, but instead of your approach, I would simply read the file into a string variable and then replace all occurrences of '01' with '10'. Your code would look something like this.

```
with open('testPy.txt', "r+") as f:
    data = f.read().replace('01', '10')
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(data)
```

The seek(0) function sets your file offset to the beginning of the file. Writing from this point will therefore overwrite the entire file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but i dont want to replace the entire file i want to replace the line only between start and end